# How to open a new window in XAML with Prism and Unity?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, unity-container, prism-4

I'm new to WPF and Prism. Currently I'm doing an application using Prism with Unity that requires me to open up a new window where I have fields to enter data and submit it. I created a view where to enter the data. But cannot figure out how to invoke it.

I have the following in xaml:

```
<Button prism:Click.Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenNewWindowCommand}" Grid.Row="2"
ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to open New Window." Width="75" >
```

What should I write in xaml in order to accomplish that or do I need to write some code in OpenNewWindow command to open it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should register your view:

```
container.RegisterType<Object, SupplierEditView>(ModuleViewNames.SupplierEditView, new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

then in your command in viewmodel you should write something like that:

```
  var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
            var url = ModuleViewNames.SupplierEditView;
            var q = new UriQuery();
            q.Add("Id", SelectedItem.Id.ToString());

            regionManager.RequestNavigate(PrismRegions.Documents, url + q, (e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());

            });
```

`ModuleViewNames.SupplierEditView` is a string in dictionary of your views' names

Comment: @GlenThomas, that depends on the type of region. In my case It is a self written region adapter that opens a new tab int TabControl